# Passing address as function argument

Tags: c, pointers

Which of these codes is appropriate and why ?

code1:

```
void fun(int *p)
{
  *p=200;
}

main(){
int *i_ptr;
fun(i_ptr);
printf("%d", *i_ptr);
}
```

Code2:

```
void fun(int *p)
{
  *p=200;
}

main(){
int i;
fun(&i);
printf("%d", i);
}
```

is it okay to pass pointer's address ?

Comment: Okay to pass what pointer's address to what? Neither of your examples pass a pointer's address.

Comment: What happens when you compile and run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Which of these codes is appropriate and why ?

The first one will lead to undefined behavior since `i_ptr` has not been initialized to point to a valid memory.

You can change it to:

```
int main(){
   int i;
   int *i_ptr = &i;
   fun(i_ptr);
   printf("%d", *i_ptr);
}
```

and it will be OK.

BTW, I also added `int` as the return type of `main`.

You also asked:

> is it okay to pass pointer's address ?

It is clear to me how the question is related to the code you posted.

Comment: How does this answer the question?